# Access non-static outer context from within inner record

Tags: java, oop, domain-driven-design

**DISCLAIMER** it's been a while since I've asked a question here, so be gentle with me please :)

I'm trying to produce a state from my business object, which should ideally stay encapsulated. My idea was to define a class with an internal representation and to have a way to return a state object, which would be later mapped onto different view representations. So I imagined something like:

`State state = order.State();`

where Order and State are defined like:

```
public class Order {
    private String identifier;

    record State(String number) {
        public State() {
            this(identifier);
        }
    }
}
```

**So my question is** how do I define relationship between my inner record and my outer class, so that I can access instance properties (ideally using the with the default record constructor) and map them onto immutable structure without running into static, non-static context issues?

(I left out the possibility to create an additional method like: `toState()`, on the outer class)

Comment: You don't: _nested record classes are implicitly static_. Make `State` have an `Order` member and access its properties through that.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thank you, I was wondering why I had troubles with it, but apparently there is an explanation to this issue:
"If a record class is itself nested, then it is implicitly static; this avoids an immediately enclosing instance which would silently add state to the record class." [link](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395)


Would you mind creating an answer out of your comment, since it actually answers my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the method from the record up to the class.

```
public class Order {
    private String identifier;

    public State state() {
        return new State(identifier);
    }

    record State(String number){}
}
```